# Maximum upload file size not reflecting to phpinfo()

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem is that when I check to wp-admin/media-new.php I see Maximum upload file size: 8 MB. Now I change the php.ini located at /usr/lib/php.ini I change the upload_max_filesize to 64M and post_max_size 64M. Then when I checked back to wp-admin/media-new.php it is now 'Maximum upload file size: 15M' it should be 64M

I even try following this http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/ but it doesn't help it. it looks like it is limited to 15M? I try to change the post_max_size to 14M then it reads now on wp-admin/media-new.php to 'Maximum upload file size: 14M' it looks like it only limits to 15M. I restarted the apache but still it won't work and it only shows 15M

I checked the phpinfo() and the file loaded is correct which is /usr/lib/php.ini

Is there any settings in wordpress that is limiting the upload file size except on the network setting? no right? What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using Wordpress MU?

Comment: Check your theme functions file for lines like these `@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '15M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', 15M');`

Comment: @unixarmy Did you mean if I use multisite? Yes I used multisite and the issue is in the main site and not in the subsite.

Comment: @Mihai I already checked but I have not seen that code on my theme functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Fixed my issues. Here are what I've learned:

1) Make sure there are no conflict with your php.ini.. I checked my phpinfo() and the file loaded is /usr/local/lib/php.ini however there is php.ini placed in the wp-admin/ folder so I deleted it and this cause overriding the setting.

2) If you are running multisite make sure that 'Max upload file size' option in wp-admin/network/settings.php is correct based on your desire cause this will reflect in the main site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this cod ein .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size           128M
php_value upload_max_filesize     128M
php_value memory_limit            500M
</IfModule>
```

Change file size as your requirement.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: @ujjwal Hi, I added that code on my .htaccess but it doesn't work still it is limiting to 15m.

Comment: you are using localhost or your project is in live server?

Comment: This is working code , revert the change you have made in your .ini file ,let it be what it was earlier and check whether it works or not. It must work because i used this piece of code several time. Cheers !!

Comment: @Ujjwal Im on my develpment site same server with my live site. Yes the code is working however the wordpress is limiting only to 15M and cannot reach greater than 15M. for example if I set it to 13M of post_max_size and then when you check it on the wordpress admin then it says max upload size is 13M. However if I set it to like 50M then when I checked to wp-admin it says 15M only... looks like it cannot reach greater than 15M.

Comment: @Ujjwal Now I tried to disable my multisite and then it increase to 32M... looks like wordpress divided the upload max size? :) but still it doesn't match to my php.ini which I set to 64M.